# App Store Review, login-enabled apps?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, app-store

Quick question for anyone who is well informed on how the Apple iOS App review process works:

If I have an app that requires a login to use from a site that is not released yet, how does Apple test the application for crashes and such? Is this against the guidelines?

The thing is even when the site launches, which will be a day after the date I request the app to release by, only members of a certain community will be able to use it...

TLDR: How does Apple test iOS apps if it is login secured and they cannot obtain a login?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Apple's rejection policies. See also: [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My understanding is that any sites etc that an app is dependant upon must be active at the time of submission in order for apple to correctly review the application - certainly on the apps I've submitted that refer to some kind of website I've always had to have something present and functioning at the appropriate web address.

If apple can't review the app they will fail it - without knowing your app it's difficult to be more specific - but without the login do you believe they can review it?  If not you will likely fail.

Can the provider of the website provide a dumbed down version that functions just enough to allow the app to function correctly for app submission before releasing the full site the day after approval?  Perhaps the provider can also set up a temporary redirection to another test only site which they can remove the day after launch?

Comment: well what about apps that require logins from a service that, let's say, you must pay to register on the site? How do they test it then?

Comment: You have to provide them with an account that they can use to test.

Comment: @j0k Where would I provide that information during the submission process?

Comment: @hmind: See the [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf), page 47. There is a field *"Review notes"* where you can provide the reviewer with all kind of information. You would tell them which account and password to use for testing there.

Comment: @DarkDust: thank you very much, all of you! Just out of curiosity, do you know from experience or from someone who has done this? I need to be absolutely sure before I move forward to prevent a delay in the approval =)

Comment: never mind, I read the document. Thanks again guys!

Comment: @hmind: I know from experience. The reviewer has to be able to test the full app and needs to have access to all features. If the reviewer can't be sure you're not violating any terms since he can't test it he'll be on the safe side and reject the app. So you need to provide an account for testing. For example, back when I was involved with a VoIP client for iOS, we provided the reviewers with two VoIP accounts on our servers to they could make a call. We provided the details for these accounts in the text field I've mentioned (you can write as much text in it as you want/need).

Comment: DarkDust is right, I too have provided login information before using this field on app submissions.  I have also submitted apps where the target website is not the final site but has enough basic functionality with mock data to enable the iOS app to function correctly.

Comment: I have same doubts, for login they need to create account with mobile number in our web portal. after registration they need to login our app with OTP will sent registered mobile number then only able to login, so how can i manage these kind of situation? its not possible to provide my test credential, only thing is they should register and do there login.